# Checking the size of a webpage

Tags: optimization, web, size, measurement, load-time

Im at the moment developing a very heavy website which i need to optimize becouse of the long loading time. I was wondering what kind of tools i could use to check how large a website is in terms of kb's to use that as a meassuring tool to optimize it.

Comment: Here's an article I wrote on the topic, with three very different approaches: http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/bid/236325/Website-Performance-Measurement-Tools-From-Brute-Force-to-Relative-Elegance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and the [Network Monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network) feature. And as suggested by @Artem K. in the comments section you could also take a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Comment: @Artem K., yes this is a good one. I will update my answer to include it. Thanks.